# How do I cause the timer and compare methods to execute before my Android toast goes away?

Tags: android, toast

```
/* In onclick function */ 

Toast.makeText(this,"you are right!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            timer();
            compare();
/* onclick function ends */
```

In this snippet when the dialog is popping up, the timer and compare methods are executed before the dialog goes away. How do I fix this? Can someone explain with a code snippet?

Also, I want the LENGTH_SHORT to be 400ms. How can I change that?

How can I do this simple task using alertdialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give time in miliSecond in Toast

```
Toast.make(this,"Hello",400).show();
 now// take one thread


Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable(){
try{
th.sleep(400);
timer();
compare();
}
catch(Exception e){
 e.getExption();  
 }
});
```

Comment: But the next instructions are getting executed before the dialog is done

Comment: Toast is used to show UI so that user can interact,but application doesnot stop in between, so i am editing my answer for your solution